# Adding a text field to this?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

```
JFrame messenger = new JFrame("messenger");
messenger.setVisible(true);
messenger.pack();
messenger.setSize(new Dimension(250,175));
```

I'm making a chat/message sender for a game. There isn't a real purpose; I'm just trying to extend my knowledge on this topic.

So far, obviously, this draws a box outside the game. Yay! What I want to do, however, is have a text field where the user enters the message, and a "Send" button under it.

I've done some Google searching on how to add a text field, and, well, I can't find anything that works for me. Nothing shows up.

How do I do this?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: *"..obviously, this draws a box outside the game."*  I find that anything but obvious.  WDYM by 'outside' the game?  Do you mean the game is shown in that window - wrapping it, or that window is 'outside' the main game window as in a 2nd window?  I'd hoped you had the sense to clarify in an SSCCE, since this has already attracted 3 answers that I feel are less than optimal.  -- Perhaps what this actually needs is `JOptionPane.showInputDialog(..)` which is just a few lines of code, but I will not know until I see an SSCCE.  In the meantime, I am voting to close on the basis of 'this is unclear'

Answer (score 2):

This is the same thing as the other answers, I just added a send button which you wanted as well.

```
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Chat");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    final JTextField textField = new JTextField();
    textField.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 50));

    JButton button = new JButton("Send");
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String message = textField.getText();
            System.out.println(message);
            // Send
        }

    });

    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    frame.add(textField, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    frame.add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Next time, please include all (or most representative) tests you have done and be very specific on what has not worked.  You could be making a basic mistake systematically.  Here you have 2 alternatives (JTextField and JTextArea):

```
JFrame messenger= new JFrame("Text") ;
messenger.setSize(new Dimension(250,175));
JTextField textLine= new JTextField() ;
messenger.add(textLine,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
JTextArea textArea= new JTextArea(30, 80) ;
messenger.add(textArea,BorderLayout.CENTER);
messenger.pack();
messenger.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Look [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html) on 'Using Swing components'.

`JFrame` has a method getContentPane() that you use to add buttons, texts, labels etc (in few words).

```
JFrame messenger = new JFrame("messenger");
JTextField tf = new JTextField();
tf.setOpaque(true);
tf.setColumn(30);
tf.setText("Some text");
tf.setBackground(new Color(248, 213, 131));
tf.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 180));
messenger.getContentPane().add(tf, BorderLayout.CENTER);
messenger.setVisible(true);
messenger.pack();
messenger.setSize(new Dimension(250,175));
```

Comment: `getContentPane()` is only necessary when you want to manipulate the content pane itself.  To add components, you can use the `add` method of the `JFrame` directly.  Saves some typing and perhaps adds a bit of clarity.